# Strange Firewall Connections

Tags: linux, firewall, openssh

I performed some analysis in my firewall logs and noticed that there were outgoing connections attempts to IPs that are according to VirusTotal flagged as malicious. Everything was blocked so far.

Then I noticed that there were always incoming connections (port 22) from the same suspicious IP that also appeared in the outgoing connections.

When I check the ssh logs on the system I only see failed authentications but how is it possible that there are outgoing connection attempts when there was no successful ssh authentication?

Comment: How did you determine that those were outgoing connection attempts rather than reply packets to an existing incoming connection?

Comment: I did not determine that. Is there a way to figure out If these were reply packages?

Comment: Are these logs of your computer? If so, how come these requests bypass the router's firewall?

Comment: These are logs from my host and the firewall. I see a successful incoming SSH connection for an IP to my host in the FW followed by failed outgoing connection attempts for the same IP in the FW. In the syslog file I can only see failed SSH authentications for the the IP that caused the incoming and outgoing connections. I'm wondering If this could be a normal behaviour or If something odd is going on.

Comment: Which OS? Debian,ubuntu others... Is port 22 open in the NAT router? Which firewall? UFW,firewalld,iptables,nftables.. We need some information otherwise it's a bit of divination

Comment: Please read my previous comment and my question. Of course port 22 is open. Please don't be a fool.